# What's the differences between class ProtobufEncoder and ProtobufEncoderNano in netty4?

Tags: android, netty, protocol-buffers

I find the two class in netty4 API doc and I don't know their differences exactly. Is nano related class is used for Android? If so, why we should use nano protobuf rather than normal protobuf protocol to transport data when develop android apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at the source code for both classes:

- [ProtobufEncoder](http://netty.io/4.1/xref/io/netty/handler/codec/protobuf/ProtobufEncoder.html)
- [ProtobufEncoderNano](http://netty.io/4.1/xref/io/netty/handler/codec/protobuf/ProtobufEncoderNano.html)

The only major difference is the actual type they encode. The second is explicitly dealing with [MessageNano](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/javanano/src/main/java/com/google/protobuf/nano/MessageNano.java), which belongs to the javanano code generator and runtime. As the docs quote **"JavaNano is a special code generator and runtime library designed specially for resource-restricted systems, like Android"**, hence i guess it is your choice and it depends on the capabilities of the device your application will run.